# docker-compose with volumes - no files in project directory in continers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to change my `docker-compose` to use volumes but my `/application` dir in containers is empty.

When i have config without volumes everything works fine:

```
volumes:
    - .:/application
```

But when i use

```
volumes:
    - code:/application

volumes:
    code:
```

i get empty `/application` in containers.

Full `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5
        container_name: youtube-playlist-mariadb
        working_dir: /application
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /var/lib/mysql/logs:/var/log/mysqld.log
            - /var/docker/mariadb/conf:/etc/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        ports:
            - "3003:3306"

    web:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: youtube-playlist-web
        working_dir: /application
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        volumes:
            - code:/application
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - "8080:80"

    php:
        build: docker/php-fpm
        container_name: youtube-playlist-php
        working_dir: /application
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        volumes:
            - code:/application

    node:
        image: node:12.22.1
        container_name: youtube-playlist-node
        working_dir: /application
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        volumes:
            - code:/application

networks:
    frontend:
    backend:

volumes:
    code:

x-mutagen:
    sync:
        defaults:
            ignore:
                vcs: true
        code:
            alpha: "."
            beta: "volume://code"
            mode: "two-way-resolved"
```

Edit: added mutagen config

Edit:
**SOLUTION**

I added this config to docker-compose

```
volumes:
    code:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: $PWD
            o: bind
```

Comment: `code` is a new volume and there is nothing in it, so the `/applications` folder would be empty. What would you like there to be in it?

Comment: In `/application` folder i want to have mu current project (docker-compose is in root of it).

Its because i am trying to use mutagen https://mutagen.io/documentation/orchestration/compose.

Comment: Do you have a Docker image that contains your application in it already?  Why are you trying to use volumes here?

Comment: I dont have this image :D I am just trying to use this docker-compose config example https://mutagen.io/documentation/orchestration/compose#extension-fields

Comment: Suggestion: a correct way to post a solution is to add it as an answer and mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

when you do what you are doing, you are just creating a volume where the content of the `/application` is going to be stored.

This is different to a bind-mount as you are doing in the first example (the one you say it's working). In this case, you are binding a directory (`.`) to `/application`.